# Running C in Sublime Text 3 only shows [finished ...s]

Tags: c, sublimetext3

Running C in Sublime Text 3 only shows [finished ...s].

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Next time copy and paste the code rather than taking a picture :)
Not seeing why this basic program isn't working...

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are only compiling your program instead of running it. So sublime shows that there are no compilation errors (Finished ...s). To make it run, you have to make build system. For more read it on : [Build System](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html)

Open Sublime, click Tools -> Build System -> New Build System

Save the following code (for windows):

```
{
    "cmd" : ["gcc", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&", "${file_base_name}.exe"],
    "selector" : "source.c",
    "shell" : true,
    "working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```